# Formatting iOS date. dateFormatter with NSDate-timeago

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Hi having problems formatting my date using NSDate-timeago and NSDateFormatter. I appear to be very close but my dates are slightly off.

```
NSLog(@"date is %@", date);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
NSLog(@"my date %@", yourDate);
NSString *ago = [yourDate timeAgo];
```

date is 2014-08-05T22:40:05.122Z
 my date 2014-08-06 02:40:05 +0000

The 'my date' should be 2014-08-05 and not be clipping the 'T' like that.

the git repo is here https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo

Comment: Don't quote the `Z` in the format specifier.

Comment: @rmaddy that worked perfectly. Why is this? Not so sure why 'T' not 'Z'. thank you for the help.

Comment: 'T' is just text, and not parsed. 'Z' is a date formatting character specifying how to parse the timezone. See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Comment: "T" is just a literal in the string. The "Z" is the actual timezone of the  date. If you quote the "Z" in the formatter, the "Z" is treated a just text and the date is assumed to be local time. But in fact the "Z" in the date means it is a date in UTC time. So you want the "Z" to be processed as the timezone.

Comment: @Zaph and rmaddy thanks very much. that's a good thing to know.

Comment: BTW - this question had nothing  at all to do with the `timeAgo` method or the git repo you linked.